# Node/Express Get Example

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm curious as to the best way to attack this.

I have a route, that looks like the following

```
router.get('/weeks/:week', auth, function (req, res, next) {
  Game.find({ 'Week': req.params.week }, function(err, games) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
    res.json(games);
  });
});
```

This works. It returns each game that has the week passed in the params.

Now, I have a Pick collection and each pick has a Game Id on it. I would like to return the associated picks with each game in this same route.

How could I extend this function to get the associated picks with the games that I get back?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Attack it with fire, then let us know what are the associated picks ? What does this mean ?

Comment: How does the Pick collection relate to the Game collection? Do you only have the Game ID in it?  Or do you have some sort of reference between the two collections?

Comment: Here is my PickSchema `var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PickSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: { type: String },
    winner: { type: String },
    correct: { type: Boolean },
    game: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Game' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Pick', PickSchema);`

Comment: Here is my GameSchema `var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var GameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Home: { type: String, required: true },
    Away: { type: String, required: true },
    Week: { type: Number },
    Game: { type: Number },
    Date: { type: String },
    Time: { type: String },
    HomeScore: { type: Number },
    AwayScore: { type: Number },
    Winner: {type: String}
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Game', GameSchema, 'games');`

Comment: But those can both be edited/changed if need be

Comment: You did not specify relation between Pick and Game. As I can see current schema, 1 pick may have multiple games that mean either one to many or many to many relationship

Comment: Thanks @ArifKhan I got that swithced around so on the PickSchema I have one game Id and on the Game Schema i have an array of Picks

Answer (score 1):

You should update Pick schema and then use populate function. This example may help you

Update PickSchema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var GameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Home: { type: String, required: true },
    Away: { type: String, required: true },
    Week: { type: Number },
    Game: { type: Number },
    Date: { type: String },
    Time: { type: String },
    HomeScore: { type: Number },
    AwayScore: { type: Number },
    Winner: {type: String},
    pick: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Pick' }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Game', GameSchema, 'games');
```

and then use populate function in you router

```
router.get('/weeks/:week', auth, function (req, res, next) {
    Game
    .find({ 'Week': req.params.week })
    .populate('pick')
    .exec(function (err, games) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.json(games);
    });
});
```

You have have a look [mongoose populate function](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Note: Please do not forgot to add pick into game while create game model

I hope this will help you